# Mac OS X - first character typed shows up late

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook

On my MacBook Pro, sometimes I'll go to my address bar and type

> superuser.com

and it'll come out as

> upersuser.com

The first character seems to be waking up the keyboard or something, and the actual character I typed shows up in the middle of the keys after that.

Once it's awake and warmed up, it's never a problem again.  But leave it for 60 seconds even, and it'll go back to this slightly-off behavior.

Things I have installed that might have something to do with the keyboard queue:

- LaunchBar
- TextExpander
- SizzlingKeys

But all of these things have been there a *long* time, and this has only been acting up for a couple weeks.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Nah, you've just got your localization set to 'Pig Latin'...

Answer (score 2):

Which version of OS X are you running?

I know that on Leopard, there's a Keyboard Firmware Updater application (I can't find it on Snow Leopard).
Maybe you could try to run it, see if there's an update. Your problem was a known issue a few month (year?) ago.

If I remember correctly, the application was under `/Applications/Utilities`.

Comment: To clarify, Keyboard Firmware Updater is for the standalone Aluminum keyboards. Built-In Keyboard Firmware Updater from http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/apple/firmware_hardware/macbookmacbookprokeyboardfirmwareupdate10.html is for some MacBook Pros.

Comment: Everything I downloaded from Apple indicates that "this computer does not need the update" so I haven't been successful yet.  Haven't seen the behavior in a while, either, though.